# Capture "tap" event with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I capture a user's "tap" event with pure JS? I cannot use any libraries, unfortunately.

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut Nothing to be sorry about

Comment: comment: [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952625/20738837) DON'T ; ;
';

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `click` event is triggered on mouse click as well as on a touch click.

The `touchstart` event is triggered when the screen is touched.

The `touchend` event is triggered when the touch ends. If the default action is prevented, a `click` event will not trigger.

http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/

Comment: @DineshKumarDJ feel free to post some example code as a separate answer. A comment to another answer isn't a good place to post it because people then can't judge the quality of your suggestion.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Sure have deleted the comment, will add as a seperate answer

Comment: We noticed that click events do not fire in safari mobile when tapping the element. touchend works for us but clicks never fire

Comment: Since this doesn't say anything about duration I don't see how answers the question about a tap event.

Answer (score 8):

There are `touchstart`, `touchend` and other events. You can add event listeners for them in this way:

```
var el = document.getElementById('test');
el.addEventListener('touchstart', touchHandler);
```

More information about native DOM events you can find on [MDN webstite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/TouchEvent).

Answer (score 7):

This is not my code but I can't remember where I got it from, used successfully. It uses jQuery but no extra libraries or plugins for the tap handling itself.

```
$.event.special.tap = {
    setup: function(data, namespaces) {
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.bind('touchstart', $.event.special.tap.handler)
             .bind('touchmove', $.event.special.tap.handler)
             .bind('touchend', $.event.special.tap.handler);
    },

    teardown: function(namespaces) {
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.unbind('touchstart', $.event.special.tap.handler)
             .unbind('touchmove', $.event.special.tap.handler)
             .unbind('touchend', $.event.special.tap.handler);
    },

    handler: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.data(event.type, 1);
        if (event.type === 'touchend' && !$elem.data('touchmove')) {
            event.type = 'tap';
            $.event.handle.apply(this, arguments);
        } else if ($elem.data('touchend')) {
            $elem.removeData('touchstart touchmove touchend');
        }
    }
};

$('.thumb img').bind('tap', function() {
    //bind tap event to an img tag with the class thumb
}
```

I used this for a project exclusively for iPad, so might need tweaking to work for desktop and tablet together.

Comment: this code also circumvents the tap lag you get with using the regular click handler

Comment: This isn't pure JS as you point out, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Derek yes, but it's useful to others

Comment: @NieDzejkob, it's not a useful answer to this question. It's easy enough to find solutions with jQuery or other libraries, but sometimes a dev is restricted and cannot use a library, which is why the OP specified "pure JavaScript". If you want to point at a jQuery answer in a comment, as Dinesh does above, that is fine.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little script myself. It's not in pure-JS, but works fine for me.
It prevents executing the script on scrolling, meaning the script only fires on a 'tap'-event.

```
$(element)
        .on('touchstart', function () {
            $(this).data('moved', '0');
        })
        .on('touchmove', function () {
            $(this).data('moved', '1');
        })
        .on('touchend', function () {
            if($(this).data('moved') == 0){
                // HERE YOUR CODE TO EXECUTE ON TAP-EVENT
            }
        });
```

Comment: The question is clear about "pure JS" and "I cannot use any library"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I still don't see any comprehensive pure-js solutions here, so here's mine based on the very valuable information from everyone else in this thread:

```js
const onClickOrTap = (element, handler) => {
  let touchMoveHappened = false
  element.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
    // on mobile this is the 1st event that happens
    touchMoveHappened = false
  })
  element.addEventListener('touchmove', () => {
    // on mobile this might get triggered in which case the
    // click or tap will get cancelled
    // we'll keep a track of it
    touchMoveHappened = true
  })
  element.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
    // happens after touchstart, but before click
    // if touch happened then we'll exit
    if (touchMoveHappened) {
      return
    }
    // calling preventDefault() will make sure the
    // subsequent click will not get triggered
    e.preventDefault()
    // at this point we are ready to call our original handler
    handler(e)
  })
  element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // this will only get triggered on desktop
    // because we call preventDefault for the "touchend" event
    handler(e)
  })
}

const btn = document.querySelector('button')
onClickOrTap(btn, (e) => {
  // will get triggered when the btn is clicked
  // or tapped, but not when scrolling on mobile
})
```

And for people using typescript:

```
declare const onClickOrTap: (element: Element, fn: (e: Event | MouseEvent<Element, globalThis.MouseEvent>) => void) => void
```