# Enable fast repeated clicks on button in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If you look on iOS lock screen where you enter pin, you can fast press twice some button eg twice 0, and it will record both presses fast, but if i put in react / javascript such button like that and press it twice fast, only one press is detected. I even tried to not use onClick where is obviously some delay but tried to use onMouseDown but no change.

How to enable fast click in js / react, while not breaking the unintended clicks while scrolling eg.

Comment: This answer can be usefull, use touch event for better click speed on mobile, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358292/capture-tap-event-with-pure-javascript

Comment: Need more context.. Can you create a codesandbox demo?